# Remove duplicate product link from WooCommerce Page Row Actions

Tags: admin, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm desperately trying to remove the duplicate link from the WooCommerce Admin Product listing (page_row_actions).

```
//Remove duplicate button from product list
    function my_duplicate_post_link($actions, $post) {
      $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        //if( $product->is_type( 'booking' ) ){
        //unset($actions['edit']);
        unset($actions['admin_action_duplicate_product']);
        unset($actions['dupe_link']);
        unset($actions['dupe_links']);
        unset($actions['duplicate']);
        unset($actions['duplicate_product']);
        unset($actions['duplicate_product_action']);
        return $actions;
        //}
    }
    add_filter('post_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 10, 1);
    add_filter('page_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 10, 1);
```

Not sure what else to try but can't get rid of it :(

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quickie

> Run only **when** you need to run and only run **where** you need to run

Your code is almost there but you are not running at the particular time,if we use the your code it runs first and then filtered again by WooCommerce. So we have two options.

1. **Change priority of the filter**
2. **Hook the code to run properly**

I think just unsetting `$actions['duplicate']` should work , i'm unsure why you have other variables also(Let me know if you have a purpose).

### Change priority of the filter

```
function my_duplicate_post_link($actions, $post) {

    // The following checks WHERE we should run if not products just return
    if ( $post->post_type != 'product' ) {
        return $actions;
    }

    $product = get_product( $post->ID );
    unset($actions['duplicate']);
    return $actions;
}

// Notice priority changed from default 10 to 15(anything greater than 10)
// Priority defines WHEN we should run
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 15, 2);
add_filter('page_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 15, 2);
```

### Hook the code to `init`

```
add_action('init','wpse_227130_hook_properly');

function wpse_227130_hook_properly() {
    add_filter('post_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2);
    add_filter('page_row_actions', 'my_duplicate_post_link', 10, 2);
}
```

Remember **`init`** action runs after all plugins loaded and best place to run code.

Comment: Thanks, the priority solved it. Somehow I assumed the default priority was correct since it worked for the other row actions. The reason why I had so many actions was because I thought I somehow had the wrong name in place. Indeed, the only unset needed is `unset($actions['duplicate']);`